# Mirror Modifier, cant move my object closer/over axis. Clipping is not woorking

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier, empty

I mirrored my object (rings on the bottom of the object) on a empty object that i placed right in the middle (Only way to creae what I want I think). So now I want to merge the Area that is on top but I cant move it closer to eachother with clipping on. If I turn clipping off I can mmove it further but then it doesnt merge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Moving the mirror modifier to the top was the solution